# Initializing pointers in a struct in a minimum of source lines

Tags: c

I'm currently new to C programming, and appreciate for any tip.

Is there a shorter way to initialize struct pointers in C without removing the pointer tags?

```
typedef struct {
    int x, y, z;
} Point3;

typedef struct {
    Point3 *pos, *direction;
} Vector;

int main() {
    Vector *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(Vector));
    p->pos = malloc(sizeof(Point3));
    p->direction = malloc(sizeof(Point3));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does _without removing the pointer tags?_ mean? and this is too short, you should check that `malloc` didn't return `NULL`.

Comment: If I use "p->pos" or "p->direction" directly after "p = malloc(sizeof(Vector));"  then the program crashes. Is there a method to initialize all of the pointer memory for *pos and *direction in a single line?

Comment: Why are you using `malloc`? what are you going to do with the struct later?

Comment: You could redesign the `Vector` type so it was `typedef struct { Point3 pos; Point3 direction; } Vector;` and that would avoid two of the three memory allocations.  Pragmatically, you could probably use `Vector *p = malloc(sizeof(Vector) + 2 * sizeof(Point3)); if (p != 0) { p->pos = (void *)((char *)p + sizeof(Vector)); p->direction = (void *)((char *)p + sizeof(Vector) + sizeof(Point3)); }` and get away with it, but I don't think it would be sanctified by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a shorter way — one which is one `malloc()` call shorter.

```
Vector *p = malloc(sizeof(Vector));
if (p != 0)
{
    p->pos = malloc(2 * sizeof(Point3));
    if (p->pos != 0)
        p->direction = &p->pos[1];
}
```

Allocate an array of 2 `Point3` values.  `p->pos` points to the first, and `p->direction` points to the second (or vice versa).

It is still 3 statements (plus error checking) and two calls to `malloc()`, though.

In practice, you could almost certainly get away with:

```
Vector *p = malloc(sizeof(Vector) + 2 * sizeof(Point3));
if (p != 0)
{
    p->pos = (void *)((char *)p + sizeof(Vector));
    p->direction = (void *)((char *)p + sizeof(Vector) + sizeof(Point3));
}
```

I am not sure that is sanctioned by the C standard, but I can't immediately think of a plausible platform configuration where it would actually fail to work correctly. It would fail if you found some bizarre platform where addresses were 16-bits each but `int` was 8 bytes and had to be 8-byte aligned, but that's hardly plausible.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it makes far more sense to put the `Point3` members directly in the `Vector`, instead of pointers. Fewer allocations, less memory fragmentation, fewer de-references, fewer cache-misses.

```
typedef struct {
    int x, y, z;
} Point3;

typedef struct {
    Point3 pos, direction;
} Vector;

int main(void) {
    /* Local (stack) allocation of a Vector, initialized to all zeros */
    Vector v = {};    

    /* Dynamic (heap) allocation of a Vector, initialized to all zeros */
    Vector *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(Vector));
    if (!p) {
       return 1;  // failure
    }
    *p = (Vector){};

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `main()` could even be `Vector v = { 0 };`

Comment: @MattMcNabb Edited, thanks.  Also, the `0` is unnecessary; empty braces suffice.

Comment: `= { } ;` is illegal in C  (it's a C++ feature)

Comment: GNU extension, perhaps? It works fine under GCC's default options (in C)

Comment: try with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11` (or c99 or c89)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no other way. You can simplify memory allocation with another function, like this

```
Vector* allocate_vector( ) {
  Vector* v = (Vector*)malloc( sizeof(Vector) );
  if( v == NULL ) {
    /**/
  }
  v->pos = (Point3*)malloc( sizeof(Point3) );
  if( v->pos == NULL ) {
    /**/
  }
  v->direction = (Point3*)malloc( sizeof(Point3) );
  if( v->direction == NULL ) {
    /**/
  }
  return v;
}
```

And then use it, when you need new `Vector`.

```
Vector* v = allocate_vector( );
```

Comment: You could improve that code with: `Vector *allocate_vector(void) { Vector *v = malloc(sizeof(Vector)); if (v != NULL) { v->pos = malloc(sizeof(Point3)); v->direction = malloc(sizeof(Point3)); if (v->pos == NULL || v->direction == NULL) { free(v->pos); free(v->direction); free(v); v = NULL; } } return v; }`  This handles allocation errors by returning NULL and avoids memory leaks.